# How to show $\operatorname{rad}(J) \subset \operatorname{rad}(I)$ implies $V(I) \subset V(J)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I would like to show

> $\operatorname{rad}(J) \subset \operatorname{rad}(I)$ if and only if $V(I) \subset V(J)$.

Suppose $V(I) \subset V(J)$, i.e., if $P \supset I$, then $P \supset J$. Then $\bigcap_{P \supset I} P \supset \bigcap_{P \supset J} P$ hence $\operatorname{rad}(J) \subset \operatorname{rad}(I)$.

---

However, I am having trouble showing the converse:

If $\operatorname{rad}(J) \subset \operatorname{rad}(I)$, then $\bigcap_{P \supset J} P \subset \bigcap_{P \supset I} P$. However, this is just an intersection of prime ideals and it does not immediately imply that the sets on the left hand side are in the intersection of the sets on the right hand side.

But, Hartshorne's book just states this as if it follows immediately. I don't see how.

Comment: It should be obvious if you remember that  $\operatorname{Rad}I= \bigcap\limits_{P\supset I}P$ and similarly for $\operatorname{Rad}J$.

Comment: @Bernard That's exactly what I wrote: that it's not so obvious from that fact.

Comment: For me, it's a tautology: if the hypothesis is $\operatorname{Rad}J\subset\operatorname{Rad}I$, you just have to replace each of them with its value  as an intersection of prime ideals. Or did I misunderstand what you mean?

Comment: @Bernard I did that step above too. I just got caught up with trying to show that if $Q$ was a prime in the intersection $\bigcap_{P \supset J} P$ then $Q$ was also a prime in the intersection $\bigcap_{P \supset J} P$. But I think that was the wrong approach.

Comment: @Bernard A better way was as I wrote in the comment to the answer below: If $Q \in V(I)$, then $\bigcap_{P \supset J} P \subset \bigcap_{P \supset I} P \subset Q$. So, $J \subset \mathrm{rad}(J) \subset Q$ hence $Q \in V(J)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $I\subset Q$ where $Q$ is a prime ideal,  then $\cap_{I\subset P} P\subset Q$,  so $\sqrt{I} \subset Q$,  hence $J\subset \sqrt{J} \subset \sqrt{I} \subset Q$.

Comment: So, if $Q \in V(I)$, then $\bigcap_{P \supset J} P \subset \bigcap_{P \supset I} P \subset Q$. So, $J \subset \mathrm{rad}(J) \subset Q$ hence $Q \in V(J)$.